# Combinação entre 4 números em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-select, classificação, order-by, combinações

SGBD: MySql

Problema: Listar todas as possibilidades de combinações entre os números "1,2,3,4", de forma que não se repitam entre eles.

Exemplo:

```
1
2
3
4
12
13
14
21
23
24
31
32
34
41
42
43...
```

Comment: Não se trata de exercicio rsrs...Vai ser em SQL. Já existe uma tabela com os IDs.

Answer (score 8):

Meio estranho precisar fazer isso em SQL, mas tendo uma tabela com os dígitos, basta fazer um `CROSS JOIN` com ela mesma:

```
SELECT CONCAT(d1.digito, d2.digito)
FROM digitos d1
CROSS JOIN digitos d2
WHERE d1.digito <> d2.digito
```

<sup>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67aea/2)</sup>

Isso funciona para combinações de dois dígitos. Com um a quatro dígitos é mais complicado, e SQL não é a ferramenta adequada para se resolver isso... Mesmo assim, aqui vai, considerando que a tabela de dígitos contenha `NULL`, `1`, `2`, `3` e `4`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(d1.digito, IFNULL(d2.digito,''), IFNULL(d3.digito,''), IFNULL(d4.digito,''))
FROM digitos d1
LEFT JOIN digitos d2
ON d1.digito <> d2.digito
OR d2.digito IS NULL

LEFT JOIN digitos d3
ON (d2.digito <> d3.digito AND d1.digito <> d3.digito)
OR d3.digito IS NULL

LEFT JOIN digitos d4
ON (d1.digito <> d4.digito AND d2.digito <> d4.digito AND d3.digito <> d4.digito)
OR d4.digito IS NULL

WHERE d1.digito IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY 0+CONCAT(d1.digito, IFNULL(d2.digito,''), IFNULL(d3.digito,''), IFNULL(d4.digito,''))
```

<sup>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/074cea/10)</sup>

Comment: Perfeito! Isso mesmo que estava precisando! Vai me ajudar em uma Stored Procedured que estou elaborando...muito obrigado!