# Combinação de digitos de A a Z (Crosse Join)

Tags: array, lógica, combinações, join

Estou fazendo um algoritmo que dá a combinação em 4 dígitos de A a Z.
Fiz usando vetores em Pascal assim:

```
var
  i:integer;
  j:integer;
  k:integer;
  l:integer;
    vect1:array[1..26] of string;
    vect2:array[1..26] of string;
    vect3:array[1..26] of string;
    vect4:array[1..26] of string;
    aux:array[1..26] of string;

  Wordlist:text;

begin
  aux[1]:= 'a';
  aux[2]:= 'b';
  aux[3]:= 'c';
  ...
  aux[24]:= 'x';
  aux[25]:= 'y';
  aux[26]:= 'z';



  Assign(Wordlist, 'Wordlist.txt');
  Rewrite(Wordlist);

  for i:= 1 to 26 do
  for j:= 1 to 26 do
  for k:= 1 to 26 do
  for l:= 1 to 26 do
    begin
    vect1[i]:= aux[i];
    vect2[j]:= aux[j];
    vect3[k]:= aux[k];
    vect4[l]:= aux[l];
        WriteLn (vect1[i],vect2[j],vect3[k],vect4[l]);
    Write(Wordlist, vect1[i],vect2[j],vect3[k],vect4[l],' ');
    end;
  Close(Wordlist);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

> Quando roda o programa imprime:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
...
zzzx
zzzy
zzzz
```

[image: Codigo Pascal]

O problema aqui é que o algoritmo depende de um contador, o que leva um tempo razoável, já que o programa imprime cada combinação (de 1 em 1 pra cada letra diferente [aaaa; aaab; aaac; etc.] ). A medida que vou aumentando o numero de dígitos o programa demora bem mais.

Se eu quiser uma combinação de 7 dígitos por exemplo (pelas minhas contas o programa imprime 250 combinações por segundo) isto iria demorar mais de um ano pra ter essas combinações:

> 7 dígitos
>
> 26 possibilidades cada (A a Z)
>
> 8.031.810.176 possibilidades de combinações
>
> Dividindo por 250 := 32127240,704 Segundos
>
> => 535454,01173 minutos
>
> => 8924,234 horas
>
> => 371 dias

Pesquisando um pouco mais encontrei, na resposta desta [Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13631/combina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-4-n%C3%BAmeros-em-mysql), e depois em outros temas, uma menção sobre `CROSS JOIN` em SQL.

Gostaria de elaborar algo deste tipo pra confrontar o tempo em que o programa vai levar pra fazer as mesmas combinações.

Gostaria de fazer no Pascal, Python ou VisuAlg mesmo (Talvez em C, pois estou aprendendo agora).

Comment: Provavelmente a demora está na exibição, e não no algoritmo. Experimente calcular o tempo sem mostrar todas as combinações na tela, e veja se algo muda.

Comment: A demora pra imprimir na tela, e nao no arquivo, será?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente, como comentado pelo @Bacoo, seu gargalo está sendo a constante impressão dos valores. No seu caso mais simples (todas as combinações com 4 dígitos de 26 caracteres) você tem `26 ^ 4 = 456.976` possibilidades, e para cada uma dessas combinações seu programa para temporariamente a execução e faz um acesso de *Input/Output* ao monitor para exibir o valor, o que tende a demorar bastante.

Fora isso, sua solução está correta. Minha solução para 6 dígitos em Python3:

```
import string

L = string.ascii_lowercase
combinacoes = []
for a in L:
    for b in L:
        for c in L:
            for d in L:
                for e in L:
                    for f in L:
                        combinacoes.append(a + b + c + d + e + f)
print(combinacoes)
```

O código acima não interrompe a execução a cada possibilidade para exibir o valor no monitor, ele primeiro calcula todas as possibilidades e só então exibi-as. Só consegui executar essa lógica para 5 dígitos (mais que isso meu computador trava), mas calculo que para 7 dígitos vá demorar pelo menos uns 45 minutos oO.

Fora isso, não tem muito mais o que você otimizar nesse algoritmo, afinal o resultado final que você quer são todas as combinações dos caracteres de `A` a `Z`, e esse resultado, por definição, vai ter tamanho de `26 ^ n`, onde `n` é a quantidade de dígitos que você quer nas combinações.

Uma última coisa a se ter em mente quando você tentar gerar todas as combinações para 7 dígitos, é que `26 ^ 7 = 8.031.810.176`. E talvez não pareça, mas esse número é **enorme** para executar em um algoritmo. Até mesmo um programa tão simples como o abaixo demorou **15 minutos** para executar no meu computador:

```
for x in range(0, 8031810176):
    a = 3 * 2
```